# Deleting old account on Windows XP after reinstall

Tags: windows-xp, user-accounts, file-permissions, my-documents

I recently had to reinstall Windows XP due to some kind of corruption.  As I didn't wipe the hard drive first, the old user accounts containing my documents are still present.  I want to get rid of these as I have restored from backup into my new account.  However, when I use Explorer, it tells me these folders are not accessible.  I guess this is some kind of authorisations issue.

Does anyone have any idea how to get rid of these folders?

Answer (score 0):

You need to take ownership of these folders. Then you can delete them.

Instructions on how to do so are on Microsoft's website: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308421

> Disable Simple File Sharing in Windows XP Professional If you are
>   using Windows XP Professional, you must disable Simple File Sharing.
>   By default, Windows XP Professional uses Simple File Sharing when it
>   is not joined to a domain. For additional information about how to do
>   this, click the following article number to view the article in the
>   Microsoft Knowledge Base:  307874
>
> How to disable simplified sharing and set permissions on a shared
>   folder in Windows XP  To take ownership of a file or a folder
>
> How to take ownership of a file You must have ownership of a protected
>   file in order to access it. If another user has restricted access and
>   you are the computer administrator, you can access the file by taking
>   ownership.
>
> To take ownership of a file, follow these steps: 1.Right-click the
>   file that you want to take ownership of, and then click Properties.
>   2.Click the Security tab, and then click OK on the Security message (if one appears).
>   3.Click Advanced, and then click the Owner tab.
>   4.In the Name list, click Administrator, or click the Administrators group, and then click OK.
>
> The administrator or the administrators group now owns the file.  To
>   change the permissions on the file that you now own, follow these
>   steps:1.Click Add.
>   2.In the Enter the object names to select (examples) list, type the user or group account that you want to have access to the file. For
>   example, type Administrator.
>   3.Click OK.
>   4.In the Group or user names list, click the account that you want, and then select the check boxes of the permissions that you want to
>   assign that user.
>   5.When you are finished assigning permissions, click OK.
>   6.You can now access the file.
>
> How to take ownership of a folder You must have ownership of a
>   protected folder in order to access it. If another user has restricted
>   access and you are the computer administrator, you can access the
>   folder by taking ownership.
>
> To take ownership of a folder, follow these steps: 1.Right-click the
>   folder that you want to take ownership of, and then click Properties.
>   2.Click the Security tab, and then click OK on the Security message (if one appears).
>   3.Click Advanced, and then click the Owner tab.
>   4.In the Name list, click your user name, or click Administrator if you are logged in as Administrator, or click the Administrators group.
>   If you want to take ownership of the contents of the folder, select
>   the Replace owner on subcontainers and objects check box.
>   5.Click OK, and then click Yes when you receive the following message:  You do not have permission to read the contents of directory folder
>   name. Do you want to replace the directory permissions with
>   permissions granting you Full Control? All permissions will be
>   replaced if you click Yes.
>
> Note folder name is the name of the folder that you want to take
>   ownership of.
>   6.Click OK, and then reapply the permissions and security settings that you want for the folder and its contents.